# How to track "popularity" of a WordPress post (views, shares) to present the "hottest" posts in category?

Tags: wordpress

I can code, but don't know much about WordPress internals, so would appreciate any advice or instructions. I am looking for a solution to present the posts on my site in the order of popularity. I am thinking of the following signals:
- number of views
- number of times a download link inside the post was clicked
- number of likes on FB (currently using Monarch plugin)

Please help me to figure out how to get those inputs recorded with WP. When available a no-code solution like plugin will be more preferred unless it has some considerable issues. Examples or tutorials would also be great.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a couple of options, first you could use a plugin which would be the easiest way to solve your issue:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-popular-posts/

Or you can take a no-plugin approach and do something similar to this:

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-track-popular-posts-by-views-in-wordpress-without-a-plugin/

I'm not sure how you'll go finding a solution that will integrate page views with social sharing, that would require popularity being abstracted from page views themselves and another counter being created and incremented via a callback from your social API's.